# Extracting Date column from a csv file and aggregate rows according to date in different csv file

Tags: r, csv, split

I need an R script to separate the date column from a csv file, and to aggregate the rows with same date in separate date file.

Following is the structure of my csv file-

```
dat <- read.table(text = 
                    "2012-04-02 10:01:23.757,BALL,2012-04-20 00:00:00.000,0,0,0,4199,4180,10,4260,30
                  2012-04-02 10:01:23.763,GLOVES,2012-05-18 00:00:00.000,0,0,0,4369,4356,20,4424,10
                  2012-04-03 10:01:25.200,PAD,2012-04-20 00:00:00.000,0,0,0,4199,4190,10,4258,30
                  2012-04-03 10:01:26.360,WICKETS,2012-04-20 00:00:00.000,0,0,0,4199,4190,10,4255,20
                  2012-04-04 10:01:27.503,BELLS,2012-04-20 00:00:00.000,0,0,0,4199,4190,10,4255,30
                  2012-04-04 10:01:28.650,SHOES,2012-05-18 00:00:00.000,0,0,0,4369,4358,10,4424,10
                  2012-04-05 10:01:29.773,KITBAG,2012-04-20 00:00:00.000,0,0,0,4199,4190,10,4252,10
                  2012-04-05 10:01:29.777,HELMET,2012-05-18 00:00:00.000,0,0,0,4369,4359,20,4424,10", sep = ",")
```

This is just the small part of the csv file.
I want this complete file to be separated on the basis of date.

Ex- 
BALL and GLOVES having same date i.e 2012-04-02, so it should go under a single separate file namely 20120402.

Similarly for other dates also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to convert your date to `?POSIXct` beforehand. Thus, you can select the rows based on the corresponding columns.

```
dat$V1 <- as.POSIXct(dat$V1, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

setwd("/your/desired/output/path")
for (i in unique(format(dat$V1, "%Y-%m-%d"))){
  tmp <- dat[format(dat$V1, "%Y-%m-%d") == as.POSIXct(i, format = "%Y-%m-%d"),]
  write.table(data.frame(tmp), 
              file = paste(format(as.POSIXct(i), "%Y%m%d"), ".csv", 
              sep =""), sep = ",", 
              col.names = F)
}
```

Comment: I didn't understood anything from it.

Comment: you have to approve the editing, then you are able to use the code. `dat` is your csv extract.

Comment: Basically I want that, extract the all unique dates from the csv file and make that unique extracted dates as a separate csv file and in that all the rows which have same date, should come under one date file.

Comment: can you tell me in above code, how are you splitting the dates and segregating the rows having same date under single date.csv file?

Comment: The column V1 contains dates-time formatted values (e.g. `2012-04-02 10:01:23.757`). The POSIXct object created in line 1 of the answer can be tructuated to the date only by `?format.POSIXct`. Thus, you can identify all `?unique` dates in the data set. Afterwards in line 4 ( `tmp <- .......`) you only select the rows which represent the specific date of the for-loop run.

Comment: in what filename you are saving the things, as I am not able to figure it out.

Comment: It will be put into your WD. I changed the code. The name of the file will be generated dynamically, e.g. "20120402.csv"

Comment: Output of the code is just giving NA.csv. when I write cat NA.csv it shows - "tmp"
"1" NA

Comment: had a little typo. I changed the code so it will work.

Comment: Thank you loki. you are life saver.

Comment: Please help me for below type of file- BAT,01-02-2012,13:55,105,Mumbai
BALL,01-02-2012,14:12,395,Delhi
GUARD,01-02-2012,12:22,1200,Jaipur
STUMPS,01-02-2012,15:16,1210,Jaipur
WICKETS,01-02-2012,11:02,5715.89,JNPT Mumbai
Output should be as above format. please help me out

Comment: a `?dput()` would be helpful. and pls extend this to your question

Comment: Your code runs perfect, but for the 1st row in the csv file, which contains title for every column, code creates a separate NA.csv file. due to this the csv file created by code doesn't contains titles. please check.

Comment: you can easily add a `header = FALSE` in the `write.table()` function. This should solve the problem.

Comment: header = FALSE is not working, it gives Error in write.table(data.frame(tmp), file = paste(format(as.POSIXct(i),  : 
  unused argument (header = FALSE)

Comment: a `?dput()` would be helpful. and pls extend this to your question